# using stored procedure to connect to db in external server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that updates a table taking the data from a source and I want to modify the stored procedure so that it takes data from a table in an external database and updates a table in the original server. Can this be achieved and how ?

Comment: Check [Linked Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See linked servers, it's treated just a synonym:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Actually synonyms are treated like linked servers..